# KQL how to find matching values in query and the original value based on an item in the same row as the matched value

Tags: azure, azure-devops, grafana, kql

So I have a table similar to this

| WorkItemId_d | Title_s | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 157 | Coke | 389 |
| 389 | Pepsi | 157 |

I need to somehow scan WorkItemId_d and find any values that match Parent, and replace the value in parent with the title of the matching WorkItemId_d to get a table output like this.

| WorkItemId_d | Title_s | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 157 | Coke | Pepsi |
| 389 | Pepsi | Coke |

So the top table is what I have now and the bottom is the end goal. I need to do this without having to manually input 50,000 lines of data. So somehow lookup a value in WorkItemId_d, match it to the number in parent. Then the title that correlates to WorkItemId_d needs to replace the numbers in Parent if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the `join` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator

for example:

```
let T = datatable(WorkItemId_d:int, Title_s:string, Parent:int)
[
    157, "Coke", 389,
    389, "Pepsi", 157,
];
T
| join kind=leftouter T on $left.WorkItemId_d == $right.Parent
| project WorkItemId_d, Title_s, Parent = Title_s1
```

| WorkItemId_d | Title_s | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 389 | Pepsi | Coke |
| 157 | Coke | Pepsi |